# ¿Cómo obtener el archivo de esquema .graphqls generado utilizando SPQR?

Tags: java

Me gusta mucho la forma en que SPQR hace que sea fácil integrar [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql) con un sistema existente, lo único que me gustaría ver es el archivo `.graphqls` que se genera para que pueda aprender más sobre la sintaxis de GraphQL ( y en particular como resuelve problemas como la herencia ).

¿Hay alguna manera de generar el archivo de esquema a partir de un código existente con anotaciones SPQR integradas?

Para proporcionar algún código, usemos el mismo código del [sitio de GitHub](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr).

Entidad:

```
public class User {   
    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private Date registrationDate;

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "name", description = "A person's name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @GraphQLQuery
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "regDate", description = "Date of registration")
    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }
}
```

Clase de servicio:

```
class UserService {

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "user")
    public User getById(@GraphQLArgument(name = "id") Integer id) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Resultado esperado:

```
type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    registrationDate: String
}

Query{
 user(Int):User 
}
```

PD: Hice la misma pregunta en el sitio [en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086525/how-to-get-the-generated-scheme-file-graphqls-using-spqr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como me respondieron en el sitio en inglés se los comparto.

Esta funcionalidad no es específica de SPQR. Todas las clases necesarias son provistas por el mismo [graphql-java](/questions/tagged/graphql-java):

```
new SchemaPrinter().print(schema);
```

Para tener una salida más detallada (con escalares, introspección de tipos etc), se le pueden proveer opciones:

```
new SchemaPrinter(
                  // Modificar según se necesite
                  SchemaPrinter.Options.defaultOptions()
                          .includeScalarTypes(true)
                          .includeExtendedScalarTypes(true)
                          .includeIntrospectionTypes(true)
            ).print(schema);
```